# I do not know how to fix the error in my PHP and PHPmyAdmin

Tags: php, html, database, phpmyadmin

**This is my hotelprocess**
I want to display the data from the database with some condition on it . For example price . I want to display the data above the price that we prompt from the form function .

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hotel</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <?php
    include 'dbh.php';
        
    $price = $_POST['price'];
        
    $query = "SELECT * FROM hotel";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        ?>
    
    <table id="Htable">
    <tr class="header">
        <th style ="width:60%;">Price</th>
        <th style ="width:40%;">Hotel Name</th>
    </tr>
     <? while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        <? if($price > $rows['h_price'])
        { ?>
                 $h_price = $rows['h_price'];
                 $n_hotel = $rows['n_hotel'];  
            ?>
             <tr>
                <td> <?= $h_price ?> </td> 
                <td> <?= $n_hotel ?> </td>
             </tr>
        <? } ?>
             <? } ?>
    </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

**This is my form page to prompt the price**
This file i want do form to do filter system for DSS .

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  PHP
</head>

<body>
  <form action="hotelprocess.php" method="POST">
    <p>
      <label>Price:</label>
      <input type="text" id="price" name="price" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="submit" name="hotel" />
    </p>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

**This is Database connection**

```html
<?php
//connect with database
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "register");
if(!$conn){
    die("connection failed:".mysqli_connect_error());
}

?>
```

Comment: Have you tried querying only those hotels that is correct for you? Like `SELECT * FROM hotel WHERE price = $price;` . Of course use > or < instead of = .

Comment: This is a mess. I see a number of typos in the code including use of `<?` opening tag and PHP variables outside PHP tags. Fix your basic syntax errors before coming looking for help.

Comment: Without any errors we can't help you and as @miken32 said your code is a mess, you have PHP opening/closing tags inside other PHP opening/closing tags.

Comment: remove unwanted `<?php ?>` tags. this tags  enough for start and end of the code

Answer (score 0):

check the price condition through the sql statement.

```
<?php
     include 'dbh.php';

    if(isset($_POST['price'])){  
        $price = $_POST['price'];

        $query = "SELECT * FROM hotel where h_price < '" .$price. "' ";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    }else{
        $query = "SELECT * FROM hotel";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    }   

    ?>
```

You can display table like this.

```
<?
 while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {


                 $h_price = $rows['h_price'];
                 $n_hotel = $rows['n_hotel'];   

         echo   ' <tr>
                <td> ='; echo $h_price; echo'  </td> 
                <td> ='; echo $n_hotel; echo'  </td>
             </tr>';

     } 

?>
```